# Python Pyqt5 QPlainTextEdit When user leaves check value

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a big app and in some `QPlaintextEdit`s.
I need to check the input when the user ends with the input he wants.
If check fails input should be updated.

I suppose it is something with focus, but I've failed find the right solution.

Sample of code i want to achieve:

```
self.plainTextEdit_2.focusOutEvent(lambda:self.check_input(Dialog14)) #### or something like this

def check_input(self,Dialog14):
    if int(self.plainTextEdit_2.toPlainText()) > num_pages:
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(str(num_pages))
```

Comment: your question is not clear,share your code to expain more clearly if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot connect to a QTextEdit's focusOutEvent.  It is not a signal but an event handler.  You must override the class and emit a signal from the event handler.

```
    self.plainTextEdit = CustomTextEdit()
    self.plainTextEdit.focus_out.connect(lambda:self.check_input(Dialog14))


class CustomTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):

    focus_out = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
        self.focus_out.emit()
```

Comment: I have 2 questions.Focus is the wright path to follow for the thing i try to do? Second because my app is rather big and the QTextEdits is more than 10 i must use a separate class for each one? Thx in advance

Comment: I believe that the focus out event is the right path for what you're trying to do.  You don't have to make a new class for each one, just use an instance of the one CustomTextEdit class.  So everywhere you would have `self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()` will now be `self.text_edit = CustomTextEdit`.